# O que são os Extras do Android SDK?

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber para que serve cada uma das opções dos "Extras" do SDK, para ver quais será preciso instalar (algumas eu sei mais ou menos, não tenho certeza).

- Android Support Repository
- Google play services for Froyo
- Google Repository
- Google play APK Expansion Library
- Google play Billing Library
- Google play Licensing Library
- Google web drive

E para onde foi o "Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library"???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O pacote Extras disponível no SDK Manager são bibliotecas disponibilizadas pela Google para facilitar o desenvolvimento de aplicativos que utilizam alguma API deles, como Google Maps, Google Billing entre outras.

Completando a resposta:

- **Android Support Repository:** Assim, como a Android Support Libray, esta biblioteca dá suporte ao desenvolvimento de funcionalidades exclusivas. Android Support Libray É uma biblioteca que disponibiliza classes que facilitam o desenvolvimento de algumas funcionalidades, como trabalhar com Fragments no android. Boas bibliotecas desse pacote e mais utilizadas são Android Support V4 e Android Support V7 AppCompat. O Android Support v7 AppComppat dá suporte ao uso de ActionBar e outros recursos disponíveis para versões do Android superiores a 3.0, mas essa biblioteca possibilita o uso disso em Androids acima de 2.1 (API 7). Você pode conferir o uso [aqui](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html).
- **Google play services for Froyo:** Essa biblioteca dá suporte ao uso da API do Google Maps V2 entre outros como o próprio Google Cloud Messaging. Ela serve tanto para Froyo como para outras versões do Android. Existe uma versão específica dessa biblioteca para o Froyo por que na versão 2.2 (API 8) do Android existe uma falha na questão de geolocalização entre outras particularidades. Então, se você for desenvolver um aplicativo que vá rodar nessa versão do Android e vá utilizar a biblioteca do Google Play Services, use essa versão da biblioteca.
- **Google Repository:** Para essa, veja se esse [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud/devtools/repo/cloud-repositories) lhe ajuda.
- **Google play APK Expansion Library:** Essa biblioteca é muito utilizada em recursos de jogos. Você pode ver uma explicação bem completa dessa biblioteca nesses links: [link1](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) , [link2](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en)
- **Google play Billing Library:** Com essa biblioteca você pode fazer seu aplicativo realizar cobranças. Se você deseja vender um recurso dentro do seu aplicativo, você pode utilizar essa biblioteca. Ela possui toda uma gama de recursos que validam a compra e a licença dos compradores.
- **Google play Licensing Library:** Com essa biblioteca, você poderá validar a licença de usuários que realizaram a compra do seu aplicativo na Play Store. Nesse caso, o aplicativo é vendido na Play Store e não possui recurso de compra dentro dele.
- **Google Web Drive:** Veja se esse [link](http://www.webdrive.com/support/webdrive/mac/v3/siteprofwiz_gdrive.html) te ajuda.

Como disse aí em cima, o **Google Cloud Messaging** está disponível na biblioteca Google Play Services.

Aqui você tem alguns exemplos de como adicionar e utilizar alguns extras.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

Comment: Show, agora deu pra entender tudo, mt obrigado.